# Kill programs when switching account on Windows10

Tags: user-accounts, process, fast-user-switching

**Is there a way killing a certain program when switching between accounts in Windows10?**

I have a VPN client running in auto-start for one account (work) on my Windows10 PC in order to be always in the office network.

I would like that this VPN client is automatically stopped (a sweet bonus would be only disconnect) every time I switch to my other account (private).

(another sweet bonus would be restarting/reconnecting when I switch back to the work account again.)

**Main reason is:** 
Most of the times for studies in my University I have to connect using another VPN client to the university network while for working I have to be connected to our office VPN.

Often I forget to shut each account off manually when switching between the accounts leading to conflicts and having to switch between the accounts two times more in order to fix my mistake.

Would appreciate if anyone has an idea on that.

Comment: To accomplish what you want you will want to logout of the user.  What is a sugar?  Edit your question

Comment: Well it doesn’t make sense in this context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a batch file to kill the program, then lock the account:

Create a new text document and change the extension from `.txt` to `.bat`. Right-click it and choose `Edit`.

Paste in the following code, replacing `program` with your VPN client's program name. You can find that in Task Manager.

```
taskkill /im program.exe
rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
```

**EDIT:** As the OP derHugo pointed out, apparently you can just use `tsdiscon` instead of calling `rundll32`. I don't know of any difference or benefit one way or the other; both seem to work to lock the account.

---

Now just save the file, and when you run it your VPN client will be killed and the account will be locked. You can also assign it a shortcut key by creating a shortcut of the batch file and going to the `General` tab on the shortcut's properties.

Comment: If the VPN client supports command line options, this might work for just closing the connection instead of killing the application. Just replace the `taskkill` line with `vpnprog.exe -close`.

Comment: Thank you! I already digged a bit into `taskkill /f /im MAYPROGRAMM.exe && taskkill /f /im explorer.exe && runas /u:<User> explorer.exe`. But your solution seems to act faster than the later. Right now I just also found `tsdiscon` .. do you know if there is any difference between your solution and `tsdiscon`?

Comment: @techturtle it is [securepoint SSLVpnClient.exe](https://www.securepoint.de/en/products/nextgen-utm-firewalls/vpn-client.html) and unfortunately it doesn't seem to support anything like that.

Comment: @derHugo Happy to help. `tsdiscon` is really intended for disconnecting from a terminal server session (i.e. Remote Desktop, typically). If you don't specify a session ID then apparently it will just lock your current session, I didn't know that. I guess you can use that instead of calling `rundll32` if you wish.

Comment: I realized `rundll32` might be the better way .. `tsdiscon` sometimes let me to a black screen a while before finally get to the login screen. Once it even just stayed black and I had to hard reset the PC ...

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, as the user can bypass this through the start menu or by Windows' built-in auto-lock timeout.